# Warum gibt es keine Lokalkonjunktionen

Tags: conjunction

Es gibt alle möglichen Sorten von Konjunktionen (temporal, instrumental, final, adversativ,...). 
Aber es gibt keine einzige lokale.

In anderen Funktionswortklassen ist das nicht so. Es gibt Lokaladverbien und natürlich auch Lokalpräpositionen. Aber auch die anderen Sorten lassen sich in den Klassen finden.

Es gibt also quasi alles in jeder Form außer Lokalkonjunktionen.

- Gibt es dazu Theorien?
- Irre ich mich und es gibt welche?

Comment: Konjunktionen bringen die Bestandteile des Satzes in logische Beziehung zueinander, d.h. z.B. zeitliche oder kausale Abhängigkeiten. Wie willst du die örtlich in Beziehung setzen?

Comment: @falkb: ... Präpositionen können es auch. "Das Buch liegt auf dem Tisch". Buch und Tisch sind Bestandteile des Satzes und ich setze sie in eine örtliche Beziehung.

Comment: "auf" verbindet aber nicht die Informationseinheiten im Satz. Konjunktionen beschreiben wie diese Verbindung aussieht. Man fragt: wie steht Informationsinhalt A zu Informationsinhalt B in Beziehung? Informationsinhalte können aber im Satz nicht örtlich zueinander stehen.

Comment: ... d.h. in anderen Worten: etwas Abstraktes lässt sich nicht in Räumlichkeit fassen, aber sehr wohl in Zeit und Logik.

Answer (score 5):

Es gibt meines Erachtens keine "Lokalkonjunktionen", weil das Konzept fehlt, das sie ausdrücken könnten.

[Subordinierende Konjunktionen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konjunktion_%28Wortart%29#Subordinierende_Konjunktionen) bringen Satzbestandteile in Beziehung zueinander. (Siehe Kommentar von falkb zur Frage) Die einzigen Beziehungen, die mir einfallen, wären der Ort eines Geschehens oder die Richtung.

Dies wird aber problemlos mit Adverbialsätzen ausgedrückt: `Man sch***t nicht, wo man isst` oder `Ich gehe, wohin ich will.`

Also sind wohl `wo` bzw. `wohin` die (einzig nötigen?) adverbialen Lokal-Konjunktionen.

Comment: Deine Beispiele sind wunderbar, aber deine Folgerung ist falsch. Die Nebensätze `, wo man isst` und `, wohin ich will` sind adverbiale Satzglieder im Hauptsatz (Adverbialsätze, genauer Lokalsätze). Aber innerhalb des Nebensatzes sind `wo` bzw. `wohin` subordinierende Konjunktionen, was man schon daran sieht, dass sie am Anfang stehen. [Es sind auch keine Adverbiale innerhalb des Nebensatzes, denn sie definieren nicht das `wollen` näher, sondern das `gehen`.]

Comment: @Toscho: ich dachte bisher,wo und wohin wären Relativpronomen, was nicht heißen soll, dass ich eine Lesung als Subj. nicht nachvollziehen könnte... es scheint logisch,sie als solche zu bezeichnen

Comment: @Emanuel Als Relativpronomen müssten sie sich auf ein Substantiv oder Personalpronomen in einem anderen Teilsatz beziehen.